# AdaGrad - Sparsity of parameters

Tags: optimization, nonconvex-programming

I read [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#AdaGrad):

> **AdaGrad** (for adaptive gradient algorithm) is a modified stochastic gradient descent algorithm with per-parameter learning rate, first published in 2011. Informally, this increases the learning rate for **sparser** parameters and decreases the learning rate for ones that are **less sparse**.

What do they mean by **parameter sparsity**?  I read that AdaGrad averages / accumulates gradients over time. Does parameter sparsity refer to how often (dense?) these gradients are accumulated? or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Yes by sparse parameters they mean that they do not receive often/large updates.
This naming is a little bit confusing, because this often happens when the data is also sparse, so that some features appear only a few times.